# how to decode utf-16 with % as delimiter string to the original form in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I am working with a mobile operator that notifies me with some kinda **utf-16** encoded **string**.
For example `'%u062a%u0633%u062a'` is the equivalent of `'تست'` in Persian. I'm not sure exactly what is the encoding of these strings. How can i convert them to their real form like `'تست'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do it is to replace `%` with `\` to make it a python literal with escaped unicode characters, and then decode it with `unicode-escape`.

```
s = b'%u062a%u0633%u062a'
print(s.replace(b'%', b'\\').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Comment: thank you but is there any way to do it directly without replacing?

Comment: FYI you can convert `str` to `bytes` by using `str.encode` method. e.g. `'%u062a%u0633%u062a'.encode()`

Comment: @MiladKh I don't think so. This is a non-standard encoding so you either have to make it conform to a certain standard or parse it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the character hex values by **%u** then lookup the unicode character using built-in function `chr`.

```
def convert_to_unicode(text):
    return_str = ''
    for character in text.split('%u'):
        if character:
            chr_code = int(character, 16)
            return_str += chr(chr_code)
    return return_str


text = '%u062a%u0633%u062a'
print(convert_to_unicode(text))
```

Output:

```
تست
```

Or you can use unicode escape as in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51204341/4310736) by blhsing.

```
def convert_to_unicode(text: str):
    # Replace %.
    text = text.replace('%', '\\')
    # Escape unicode into character.
    text = text.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
    return text
```